# Does NPM allow multiple versions of one dependency?

Tags: javascript, npm

Let's say I have 3 Node packages: PackageA, PackageB, and PackageWithPossibleCollision.

- PackageA 1.0 depends on version 3.6.0 of Lodash.
- PackageB 1.0 depends on version 4.17.21 of Lodash.
- PackageWithPossibleCollision 1.0 depends on PackageA 1.0 and PackageB 1.0.

When I run `npm install` in the PackageWithPossibleCollision package, what versions of Lodash do PackageA and PackageB get? Is it like with Maven, where it just grabs the version of Lodash from whichever library (PackageA or PackageB) that we import last, and uses that for both libraries? Or do PackageA and PackageB get their own specified versions of Lodash?

Does NPM allow multiple versions of a single dependency within one package?

Comment: https://medium.com/learnwithrahul/understanding-npm-dependency-resolution-84a24180901b Might help

Comment: I think latest version of Lodash contains features that exist in older version. Did you try it in that way ?

Take a look
https://reactgo.com/npm-install-same-package-multiple-versions/#:~:text=When%20we%20install%20a%20package,supported%20from%20the%20npm%20v6.

Comment: @seenukarthi link is behind a paywall

Comment: @GordonSeidohWorley Yes, it is, When I must have had a medium membership!